# Template class constructor with one argument in the second template throw error "constant"

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my class templates.

```
template <class T>
class test {
private:
    T a;
public:
    test (T _a){
        a = _a;
    }
    test (){}
};

template <class T>
class test2 {
public:
    test<double> first(10.2);
//                     ^ error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

    test<T> second;
    test<T> third;
    test2(){}

};

main()
{
    test2<int> object;
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get the compiler error shown in the comment above?

Comment: Please post the exact error message and specify whether you are using c++11?

Answer (score 3):

Non-static data member initializers need to use braces or an equals sign. Parentheses are not an option, probably so that the whole [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) fiasco doesn't happen with data members. Change it to one of the following:

```
test<double> first = 10.2; //option 1 (doesn't work with explicit constructor)
test<double> first{10.2}; //option 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 test<double> first(10.2);
```

this is a syntax error.

it looks like either a function declaration with a constant value in place of an argument type (illegal), or the declaration of a member variable which is being initialised with illegal syntax.